# Iterating array of 100000 indexes in web worker javascript file freezes the browser

Tags: javascript, arrays, web-worker

*web worker*

**HTML file**

```
<p> clicking web worker will iterate through 100000 indexes of array
</p>
<input type="button" onclick="startWorker()" value="web worker">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="click to display hello">
<div id="contents"></div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
function startWorker()
{
   var worker = new Worker('bigloop.js');
        worker.onmessage = function (event) {
        alert(event.data);
            worker.terminate();
        };
}
$(function()
{
  $('#btn').click(
    function()
    {
      $('<p>hello</p>').appendTo('#contents');
    }
  );
})
```

**bigloop.js**

```
var i;
var array=new Array();
for(i=0;i<100000;i++)
{
  array.push(i);
}
var n=array.length;
for ( i = 0; i <n; i += 1){
   console.log(array[i]);

}
postMessage("completed successfully. .");
```

When I click <kbd>web worker</kbd> button, it freezes the browser until the loop is executed in `bigloop.js`.

- ¿What's the use of web-worker?

Comment: Logging 100K lines from the webworker may have something to do with that?

Comment: I ran your code and I don't seem to have any problems at all. Everything from the worker is logged to the console and I can append new `p` elements until I'm waiting.

Are you sure there isn't another problem on your end?

Comment: @CanIbanoglu  I cannot append p element while the web worker is printing the array elements in the console.I agree that the web worker is executing the loop very faster.But why it still freezes the browser even though it i executed in separate thread?

Answer (score 1):

I bet it will be different when you take out the console.log line. One thing I've noticed over time: for example page load is much slower with DEV tools open. Try without logging, see what happens.

Comment: Ya.It is executing faster without logging statement.But i need to print the array elements in the console.Why it still freezes the browser while executing the loop though it is running in separate thread???